# Null Reference at DLL Call

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

This error has been bugging me for days. I am 100% sure this line of code is causing the error:

```
g_Handle = mw_create(CInt(Me.Handle))
```

mw_create is a function from an external dll:

```
  <DllImport("mwcore.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
    Public Shared Function mw_create(ByVal hWnd As Integer) As Integer
    End Function
```

The thing is, this works fine on Windows 7, but gives an annoying System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object error when run on Windows XP.

Does anyone here know why this happens?

Note: I have declared all variables and the code runs fine on Windows 7, the PC it was compiled on, but gives the null reference error on XP.

Also, I used Visual Studio 2012 (v110) to compile the DLL in C++

Comment: Could be 64 bit vs 32 bit issue, maybe?

Comment: The EXE is compiled on Windows 7 64 bit as a 32 bit EXE

Comment: Clearly you'll need to use an unmanaged debugger to find out what is going wrong.  No point in guessing at the cause without you doing this first.